# Multiple view set into router Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with DRF
I have a model

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class Person(models.Model):
    site = ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to create a viewset and serializer and I want to get the specific url:

```
/api/sites/{pk}/persons/
```

And get all persons that They have associate site
Or

```
/api/sites/{pk}/persons/{pk}
```

How can I do?

Comment: Check out the part of the tutorial on ViewSets: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers


class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Person


# views.py
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet


class PersonViewset(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Person.objects.filter(site_id=int(self.kwargs['site_id']))
```

router config will be as

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'/api/sites/<site_id>/persons', views.PersonViewset)
```

Comment: Url? Is /api/sites/<site_id>/persons/ ?

Comment: yeah..is there any problem with that?

Comment: No! Is perfect! One question, how I would can declare the router? Thanks!

Comment: @AguAguilar I've updated the answer. Hope it helps :)